# What would be a good design pattern for passing in a type, going through some conditionals, and returning an object

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

```
const someFailedAction = (caseIds, growlMessages) => {

    if (caseIds.length > 1) {
        toastr.error(growlMessages[0], errorToastrOptions);
    } else if (isCaseDetailsDisplayed) {
        toastr.error(growlMessages[1], errorToastrOptions);
    } else if (errorParts.fieldIds.length === 0) {
        toastr.error(growlMessages[2], errorToastrOptions);
    } else {
        toastr.error(growlMessages[3], errorToastrOptions);
    }
}
```

I have a bunch of conditional statements like the one above which are executed on failures of different case actions. Most of the actions have the same if/elseIf structure, but some have an additional elseIf or a subtraction of one or more.

```
const SomeOtherFailedAction = (caseIds, growlMessages) => {

    if (caseIds.length > 1) {
        toastr.error(growlMessages[0], errorToastrOptions);
    } else if (isCaseDetailsDisplayed) {
        toastr.error(growlMessages[1], errorToastrOptions);
    } else {
        toastr.error(growlMessages[2], errorToastrOptions);
    }

}
```

I was wondering if there was a good design pattern for which I could just pass in the type and array of messages without having a long, nested, repetitious switch statement.

Comment: In your case I see that inside `someFailedAction` function you have almost the same lines in each condition: `toastr.error(growlMessages[%index%], options);` Wouldn't be better to have `error` invocation at the end of the `someFailedAction` but in each condition you specify `index` for `growlMessages`

Comment: Where do `isCaseDetailsDisplayed` and `errorParts` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an array of booleans and find the index that succeeeds:

```
const i = [
 caseIds.length > 1,
 isCaseDetailsDisplayed,
 errorParts.fieldIds.length === 0,
 true
].indexOf(true);

toastr.error(growlMessages[i], errorToastrOptions)
```

Alternatively, you could store an reusable array of functions, execute one after another and return the first index where the function returns true:

```
const tests = [
 () => caseIds.length > 1,
 () => isCaseDetailsDisplayed,
 () => errorParts.fieldIds.length === 0,
 () => true
]

const i = tests.findIndex(f => f());

toastr.error(growlMessages[i], errorToastrOptions)
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I'm refactoring a bunch of code and sometimes it's hard to see a better solution when you've already seen a solution (albeit a bad one)

Answer (score 3):

Jonas solution is very efficient . Note you can DRY out what you have by setting default index and only override it in your conditionals. Then call your function once at the end

```
const someFailedAction = (caseIds, growlMessages) => {

    let idx = 3// replaces final `else` and is default

    if (caseIds.length > 1) {
        idx=0;        
    } else if (isCaseDetailsDisplayed) {
        idx = 1;        
    } else if (errorParts.fieldIds.length === 0) {
        idx= 2;        
    }// last `else` removed since already have a default

    toastr.error(growlMessages[idx], errorToastrOptions);
}
```